# Lubuntu 14.04 how to hide taskbar on second screen

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I have **Lubuntu 14.04** and a two screen configuration.

I can configure resolutions and layout with ARandR app, but the taskbar panel is showing in both screens, and I want it only in first screen.

Is it possible to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

If the first screen is smaller than the second and your LXPanel is on the bottom you should be able to achieve the desired result by merely aligning the tops of the two screens.  If the bottoms are aligned then the panel will show up on both monitors.

Answer (score 0):

This may only work if your setup is similar to mine.  If, for example, you are mirroring screens or have them above each other or something, this will not work.

My screen setup is like this.  DVI-0 is 1280x1024 and VGA-0 is 1024x768.   I only want the panel on DVI-0.

[image]

To achieve this, I right-click the panel and select Panel Settings from the menu. Under Size I set Width to 1280 pixels. This makes the panel extend across the bottom of DVI-0 and stop at its right edge, so it does not show up on VGA-0 at all.

@Rex is correct in what he says about the panel not showing up on the second screen in a setup like mine with the tops aligned, but if you do not set the panel width properly, much of the displayed information will be lost in the missing portion that extends off the right side of DVI-0.

Here is a screenshot of the full width panel, note that all the panel stuff on the right is not visible to the user (though it shows up on the screenshot)
[image]
With the panel width set to 1280 it nicely shows on the left screen.
[image]